# Sorting/Splitting a column into different view columns in one row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-view

I'm having a problem with creating a view that should split up one column of a table into three different columns in one row.

The data table looks similar to this:

[Table](http://www.youscreen.de/ulfkwxzcf63.jpg)

What i want to do is create a view for each Type (amount of types is fixed to three) where the three ID's / Serial no. of the same size for the different colors (amount of colors is also fixed to three) stand in one row, like this:

[WantedView](http://www.youscreen.de/lobtrvcsx89.jpg)

And the additional data (like weight, ...) stands after this.

What i got so far is this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Typ1]
AS SELECT 
Size AS Size, 
CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN SerialNo END AS SerialNoBlue , 
CASE WHEN Color = 'Grey' THEN SerialNo END AS SerialNoGrey, 
CASE WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN SerialNo END AS SerialNo Green
FROM [Table] 
WHERE Typ = 'Typ1'
```

Which results into something like this:

[CurrentView](http://www.youscreen.de/mngwfgpqw20.jpg)

The question for me is if there is a way to "merge" the rows where Column X is identical?

Or is there a completely different way to do this?

Comment: Please refrain from using (external) images to display data/code/etc.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a conditional aggregation

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Typ1]

AS SELECT Size AS Size,
          max(CASE WHEN Color = 'Blue' THEN SerialNo END) AS SerialNoBlue ,
          max(CASE WHEN Color = 'Grey' THEN SerialNo END) AS SerialNoGrey, 
          max(CASE WHEN Color = 'Green' THEN SerialNo END) AS SerialNo Green
FROM [Table] 
WHERE Typ = 'Typ1' group by Size
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is first group by size and then make 3 inner joins with the blue,grey and green as below:-

First I will use a memory table to simulate your data as below (you dont need this)

```
Declare @t Table (
ID int,
Size int,
SerialNo int,
Color varchar(20),
[Weight] int,
Typ varchar(20)
)
insert into @t values
(1,130,96043,'Blue',120,'Typ1'),
(2,130,96041,'Grey',120,'Typ1'),
(3,130,96055,'Green',120,'Typ1'),

(4,170,96096,'Blue' ,220,'Typ2'),
(5,170,96050,'Grey' ,220,'Typ2'),
(6,170,96040,'Green',220,'Typ2'),

(7,190,96042,'Blue' ,300,'Typ1'),
(8,190,96045,'Grey' ,300,'Typ1'),
(9,190,96070,'Green',300,'Typ1'),

(10,220,96080,'Blue' ,360,'Typ3'),
(11,220,96095,'Grey' ,360,'Typ3'),
(12,220,96093,'Green',360,'Typ3')
```

Then a query to get the desired result (you can convert it to a view)

```
;with cte as (
    Select t.Size from @t t group by t.Size
)
select cte.Size
    ,b.SerialNo [Serial no. Blue],b.ID [ID Blue]
    ,g.SerialNo [Serial no. Grey],g.ID [ID Grey]
    ,r.SerialNo [Serial no. Green],r.ID [ID Green]
    ,b.[Weight]
     from cte
    inner join @t b on b.Size=cte.Size and b.Color='Blue'
    inner join @t g on g.Size=cte.Size and g.Color='Grey'
    inner join @t r on r.Size=cte.Size and r.Color='Green'
```

output will be:-

```
Size    S.B    ID.Blue  S.Gr    ID.Grey S.G    ID.Green Weight
130     96043   1       96041   2       96055   3       120
190     96042   7       96045   8       96070   9       300
```